# Using a column both inside and outside aggregate in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to calculate z-score of a column, like so:

```
select uid, score - avg(score) / stdev(score)
from #scores
group by uid
```

However, I get the following error.

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Column '#scores.score' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

But clearly score is used in the aggregate function? This SQL statement works in Sybase, but not in SQL Server. Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you are getting is pretty clear, and I'm surprised that query ran on Sybase.  You are selecting `score` by itself in the context of an aggregation by `uid`.  This doesn't make logical sense, because it isn't clear to SQL Server *which* `score` you want to use for each `uid` group (and in general there would probably be more than one).  Your calls to `AVG` and `STDEV` are fine.  As a workaround, I propose using `AVG` and `STDEV` as analytic functions.  This would allow to access those aggregate values, but include every row, and therefore every value of `score`, in your result set.

```
SELECT
    uid,
    (score - AVG(score) OVER (PARTITION BY uid) ) /
        STDEV(score) OVER (PARTITION BY uid) score_calc
FROM #scores
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked. For the record, it's actually (score - avg(score)) / stdev(score) for z-score, I missed the brackets.